# How do I check if a message was sent in a specific channel via. channel ID discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, channel

So I'm coding a Discord bot for a friend and I need to see if a message was sent in a specific channel.
I tried a few things, asked a few people, and searched for an answer, but I couldn't find any.
This is about the closest I've gotten and I've tried changing a few objects:

```
if message.channelID == ('#858884357271322634'):
  await message.channel.send ('I checked and verified the channel.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check does not really makes sense, there is no such `message.channelID`.

Simply compare `message.channel.id` with the ID you want to and insert it correctly.

**Simple example:**

```py
if message.channel.id == 858884357271322634:
    await message.channel.send("I checked and verified the channel.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using ('') which caused the problem ig.

Comment: Yes, never put an ID into `"`. If the answer helped you feel free to accept it.