# Python | discord.py check if channel-id = xxx to proceed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make an if clause in discord.py to check if the channel is the one the bot should respond to.

With Hikari I managed to do it with:

```py
async def ping(event: hikari.GuildMessageCreateEvent) -> None:
    global link
    if event.is_bot or not event.content:
        return

    if event.content.startswith("$shares"):
        if event.channel_id != 966338808075411486:
            return
        split = event.content.split()
```

But I can't find a working solution for discord.py, how can I replcate the  `if event.channel_id != 966338808075411486:` using discord.py ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in discord.py as so:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
        return

  if message.content.startswith("$shares"):
    if message.channel.id != 966338808075411486:
      return
```

References:

[on_message event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)

[How do I check if a message was sent in a specific channel via. channel ID discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292920/how-do-i-check-if-a-message-was-sent-in-a-specific-channel-via-channel-id-disco)